# HTML5 attribute type "time" in phonegap android app hangs the app

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I have a phonegap - android app (built with jqueryMobile), with **Jquery version 1.9.1** and there is a time field (taken as input) in one of the screens. Following is the code used.

```
<td><input type="time" name="fromTime_2" value="" placeholder="Time" /></td>
<td><input type="time" name="toTime_2" value="" placeholder="Time" /></td>
```

I have 6 of these time fields in the same screens.. in a `<table>`. On my app (Android V 4.1), when I select my first time field, it works well i.e. it shows the Android Clock and I am able to select the time.
The problem starts when I select any of the other time fields. It shows the Android clock and when the "Set" button is tapped, the app hangs from there and won't respond. I have to manually "Force Stop" the app and restart.

UPDATED:- "I need only the time field here. DateTime is not required" But the problem is same even when I tried the Datetime field. It only works for one Datetime field.

NEW UPDATE:- It's showing a simple keyboard (not android clock) on my emulator - so nothing is being tracked as "time" field in the logs.

Can anyone let me know how to fix/debug this issue?

Comment: anybody there??? Need help on this please :(

Comment: good morning everyone...any help from here is very much appreciated

Comment: any answers here please?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt HTML5 supported time input type will be supported in all android platforms. 
jQuery Mobile states

> In jQuery Mobile, you can use existing and new HTML5 input types such as password, email, tel, number, and more. Some type values are rendered differently across browsers

I suggest you use jquery plugins for date/time picking.

Eg: [Datebox plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)

Fairly simple and easy to use.